# How to put the browser in the foreground on user action

Tags: ipad, html

I have created an html5 application in which I open an pdf, after opening PDF my application goes to background. Is there any option to bring it back to foreground?

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I changed the title. There's nothing specific to html5 in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pdf.js` and embed the pdf file on the same page. Then you can use the `z-index` **css property** to bring what ever element to the front. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

On your user action event handler you do something like this:

```
myElement.style.zIndex = 1000; // DOM Scripting Example (Single Element)

// or

$('#myElement').css('z-index', 1000); // jQuery Example (All elements with the "myElement" id)
```

`myElement` represents the element you wish to bring to the top.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no control of javascript over:

- the opening applications (you can't force them in the background)
- the browser itself (you can't force it in the foreground)

The best you could do is to find a full javascript pdf reader and use it to open your pdf, giving you control over it. I don't even know if such thing exists, but it is definetly a possible thing to do if you have time :-)

Regards.